# Is $\operatorname{negl}_1(n)-\operatorname{negl}_2(n) \leq \operatorname{negl}_3(n)$?

Tags: negligible

Is this statement $\operatorname{negl}_1(n)-\operatorname{negl}_2(n)\leq \operatorname{negl}_3(n)$  true for some negligible function $\operatorname{negl}_3$ and security parameter $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\negl}{\operatorname{negl}}$
\begin{align}
\negl_1(n)-\negl_2(n)&\leq \left|\negl_1(n)-\negl_2(n)\right|\\
&\leq\left|\negl_1(n)+\negl_2(n)\right|\\
&=\negl_1(n)+\negl_2(n)\\
&\leq \negl_3(n)
\end{align}

where the last statement uses the fact that the sum of two negligible functions is negligible and the rest uses the fact that $\negl_1(n)\geq0$ and $\negl_2(n)\geq0$. For a proof of the last inequality, see [this lecture on one-way functions and negligble functions (PDF)](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~sanjamg/classes/cs276-fall14/scribe/lec02.pdf).